# Running script function from editor doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I never ever programmed JavaScript and never did anything with Google Script before either. I have a fairly good understanding of Visual Basic and macros in Excel and Word. Trying to make a fairly basic program: Plow through a list of variables in a spreadsheet, make a new sheet for each value, insert a formula in this new sheet, cell (1,1).

Debug accepts my program, no issues - however, nothing at all is happening when I run the program:

```
function kraft() {
  var rightHere = 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A131");
  var loopy;
 var goshDarn = "";
  for (loopy = 1; loopy < 132; loopy++) {
    celly = rightHere.getCell(loopy,1);
     vaerdi = celly.getValue();
     fed = celly.getTextStyle();
     console.log(vaerdi & " - " & fed);
     if (vaerdi != "" && fed.isBold == false) {
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(vaerdi);
       var thisOne = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(vaerdi);
       thisOne.deleteRows(500,500);
       thisOne.deleteColumns(5, 23);
       thisOne.getRange(1,1).setFormula("=ArrayFormula(FILTER('Individuelle varer'!A16:D30015,'Individuelle varer'!A16:A30015=" & Char(34) & vaerdi & Char(34) & ")))");
    }    
  }
}
```

activeSheet could be called by name, so could activeSpreadsheet, I guess. But range A1:A131 has a ton of variables - some times there are empty lines and new headers (new headers are bold). But basically I want around 120 new sheets to appear in my spreadsheet, named like the lines here. But nothing happens. I tried to throw in a log thingy, but I cannot read those values anywhere.

I must be missing the most total basic thing of how to get script connected to a spreadsheet, I assume...

EDIT: I have tried to update code according to tips from here and other places, and it still does a wonderful nothing, but now looks like this:

```
function kraft() {
  var rightHere = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A131");
  var loopy;
  var goshDarn = "";
  for (loopy = 1; loopy < 132; loopy++) {
    celly = rightHere.getCell(loopy,1);
    vaerdi = celly.getValue();
    fed = celly.getFontWeight();
    console.log(vaerdi & " - " & fed);
    if (vaerdi != "" && fed.isBold == false) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(vaerdi);
      var thisOne = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(vaerdi);
      thisOne.deleteRows(500,500);
      thisOne.deleteColumns(5, 23);
      thisOne.getRange(1,1).setFormula("=ArrayFormula(FILTER('Individuelle varer'!A16:D30015,'Individuelle varer'!A16:A30015=" + "\"" + vaerdi + "\"" + ")))");
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT2: Thanks to exactly the advice I needed, the problem is now solved, with this code:

```
function kraft() {
  var rightHere =         SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A131");
  var loopy;
  for (loopy = 1; loopy < 132; loopy++) {
    celly = rightHere.getCell(loopy,1);
    vaerdi = celly.getValue();
    fed = celly.getFontWeight()
    console.log(vaerdi & " - " & fed);
    if (vaerdi != "" && fed != "bold") {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(vaerdi);
      var thisOne = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(vaerdi);
      thisOne.deleteRows(500,499);
      thisOne.deleteColumns(5, 20);
      thisOne.getRange(1,1).setFormula("=ArrayFormula(FILTER('Individuelle varer'!A16:D30015;'Individuelle varer'!A16:A30015=" + "\"" + vaerdi + "\"" + "))");
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the function somewhere?

Comment: ignore line with goshDarn - this was an earlier attempt to do debug :)

Comment: Teemu: I am pushing the "run" button in script window. But I know exactly where I want the code to be executed. I don't seem to have any options to do anything but hit play button within script window, though...

Comment: There is a drop down menu that contains all the functions in your script, you need to select this function (`kraft()`) there.

Comment: Hmm ... When you'll  manage to run the function, on the last line the argument for `setFormula` looks more like VB than JS. That would probably trigger an error complaining about `Char` is not defined. Also, in general, `+` operator is used to concatenate strings in JS, not `&`, which is a bitwise AND ...

Comment: Teemu: I tried to look at functions and how to insert " into string, and thought `char` was the call within JavaScript.

Comment: Titus: Where is this drop down? Within script window I have the ability to execute. Within sheet, I can access code, which will send me to the code string. I must be missing the most basic possible thing :)

Comment: Teemu: Duely noted with + operator. Hurts my VB brain to + things that aren't numerical, but fair enough ;)

Comment: Maybe this is it: In my VB brain, I am not trying to build a Function - I am trying to build a Sub. I don't want a cell to run this. I want to run this and impact cells and everything all over the place

Comment: I'm talking about the window that opens when you go to **Tools > Script Editor**. In that window, beside using the drop down, you can also use **Run > Run Function > kraft**

Comment: In my Spreadsheet, I click *Tools > Script Editor*, then get the script window, where I have the option to *Run > Run Function > Kraft* - that should be the way, yeah? But nothing happens. It pretends to run for like 8 seconds, and no changes anywhere...

Comment: If you'll continue to learn JS, you'll find out, that the same operator can be used to convert string to numbers too = ), JS has no subs ... By no means being offending, I think you'd have better changes to finish your project by learning the JS basics first, read some good tutorials etc. And remember, https://developer.mozilla.org has the most complete JS reference, and also some good tutorials ...

Comment: Teemu: Understood, and I really should. However, I am very bad at learning when I don't have a very specific problem to solve. And today I do. I don't really want to learn JS as such. I just want to plow through rows 1 to 132 and create a 5x500 sheet for each non-empty and non-bold value in column A, row 1 to 132. My code is not great, probably, but it cannot be a million miles from working?

Comment: What does the log say? view>Stackdriver logging. You could also set a breakpoint (touch the line number you want to break) and then run debug. `getTextStyle` is a undocumented method.Perhaps, you were looking for [`getFontWeight`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFontWeight()) Your code is wasting precious resources. use `getValues()` and read optimization strategies/Best Practices.

Comment: |'-'|: Log has no data. Stackdriver Log tries to load, and goes nowhere.

I can see do way too many variables, but that was meant to be "Learning through Debugging" - so I made variable calls all the way down rather than specifying exactly what was needed. In this particular case, though, I don't mind brute force. I just don't want to manually create these sheets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your script, but the main one is that you never actually call the isBold() function in your 'if' statement.

```
if (value && format.isBold() == false) {
     //do something
    }
```

Because you omitted the parentheses in 'fed.isBold', the expression never evaluates to 'true'. 'isBold' (without the parentheses) is of type Object as it's a function.

There are other issues that prevent the script from running properly:

1. Not using the **'var'** keyword to declare variables and polluting the global scope. As a result, all variables you declare within your **'for'** loop are not private to your function. Instead, they are attached to the global object and are accessible outside the function. https://prntscr.com/kjd8s5

   2. Not using the built-in debugger. Running the function is not debugging. You should set the breakpoints and click the debug button to execute your function step-by-step and examine all values as it's being executed.
   3. Deleting the non-existent columns. When you create the new sheet, you call the **deleteColums()**. There are 26 columns in total. The 1st parameter is the starting column while the 2nd one specifies how many columns must be deleted. Starting from column 5 and telling the script to remove 23 columns will throw an exception. Always refer to the documentation to avoid such errors.
   4. **console.log** doesn't exist within the context of the Script Editor. You are NOT executing the scripts inside your browser, so Browser object model is not available. Use Logger.log(). Again, this is detailed in the documentation.
   5. Your formula is not formatted properly.

JS is a dynamically typed language that's not easy to get used to. If you don't do at least some research prior to writing code, you'll be in for a lot of pain.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, and exactly the type of advice I was hoping for. Thank you so much. I will fiddle, now that I know in which direction to point my fiddling :)

Comment: @JakobMark Glad I could help. If that resolves your issue of not being able to run the script, please consider marking the question as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: And this let me to functional, if not exactly pretty, code. Question updated and this upvoted within a few seconds. Please be aware, my Sheets is in Danish, and therefore my formula has semicolons instead of commas between arguments.

Comment: `console.log` sure as heck is valid in the Script Editor! But, it goes to Stackdriver